# Decoding RSA encrypted String - BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm new to the crypto scene. I'm trying to port the `DecryptStringTest` method from the article [*Code Project - Cryptography with certificates*](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/486387/cryptography-with-certificates) to java.

I load the private key from an RSA xml format (produced via c#). I place those values in the RsaKeyValue class that contains modulus, exponent, p, q, dp, dq, inverseQ and d.

Everytime I run it, `decrypt()`, and pass on the encrypted String, I get this exception:

> BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus.

The key size is 1024. What I don't understand is why its giving me that error in the first place when the string was encrypted using the public key that was generated with the private key in c#. How could the message be bigger than the modulus? Maybe I'm loading my RSA keys incorrectly?

Any insight would be awesome. Thanks!

PS I'll be cleaning up my code. Sorry if it looks ugly. I just want this thing to run.

So far my code looks like this.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class RsaKeys {
private final String rsaDecAlgorithm = "RSA";
private static KeyFactory kf;
private static Cipher cipher;

public PublicKey publicKey;
public PrivateKey privateKey;
private RsaKeyValue rsaKeyVal = new RsaKeyValue();

public RsaKeys(String path) {
    this.rsaKeyVal = new RsaKeyValue(path);
    this.privateKey = makePrivateKey();
    //this.privateKey = makePrivateKeyTwo();
    this.publicKey = makePublicKey();

}

public String encryptString(byte[] input) {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] ret = cipher.doFinal(input);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(ret);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int base64BlockSize = (this.rsaKeyVal.getBitStrength() / 8) % 3 != 0
            ? (((this.rsaKeyVal.getBitStrength() / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4
            : (((this.rsaKeyVal.getBitStrength() / 8)) / 3) * 4;

    int iterations = encryptedString.length() / base64BlockSize;
    List<byte[]> temp = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    /**/
    System.out.println("base64BlockSize: " + base64BlockSize);
    System.out.println("Iterations: " + iterations);
    /**/

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        try {
            byte[] bytesArray = Base64
                    .decodeBase64(encryptedString.substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));

            /**/
            System.out.println("Byte Array Encrypted String Length: " + bytesArray.length);
            System.out.println("Encoded Byte Array Encrypted String: " + Base64.encodeBase64String((bytesArray)));
            /**/

            temp.add(cipher.doFinal(bytesArray));

        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] retBal = null;
    try {

        temp.stream().forEach(x -> {
            try {
                bStr.write(x);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        retBal = bStr.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bStr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return Base64.encodeBase64String(retBal).toString();
}

public String getPrivateKeyModulus() {
    RSAPrivateKey temp = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey;
    return "Modulus: " + temp.getModulus();
}

private PublicKey makePublicKey() {

    try {
        byte[] modBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getModulus());
        byte[] expBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getExponent());

        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(rsaDecAlgorithm);

        BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
        BigInteger exp = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);

        RSAPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(mod, exp);
        PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(pubSpec);

        return pubKey;
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private PrivateKey makePrivateKey() {

    try {
        byte[] modBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getModulus());
        byte[] dBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getD());

        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(rsaDecAlgorithm);

        BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
        BigInteger d = new BigInteger(1, dBytes);

        RSAPrivateKeySpec privSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(mod, d);
        PrivateKey pKey = kf.generatePrivate(privSpec);

        return pKey;
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return null;
}

private PrivateKey makePrivateKeyTwo() {

    byte[] modBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getModulus());
    byte[] expBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getExponent());
    byte[] dBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getD());
    byte[] pBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getP());
    byte[] qBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getQ());
    byte[] dpBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getDp());
    byte[] dqBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getDq());
    byte[] inverseQBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(this.rsaKeyVal.getInverseQ());

    BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
    BigInteger exp = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger(1, dBytes);
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(1, pBytes);
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(1, qBytes);
    BigInteger dp = new BigInteger(1, dpBytes);
    BigInteger dq = new BigInteger(1, dqBytes);
    BigInteger inverseQ = new BigInteger(1, inverseQBytes);

    RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec keySpec = 
            new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(
                    mod,
                    exp,
                    d,
                    p,
                    q,
                    dp,
                    dq,
                    inverseQ
                    );

    try {
        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(rsaDecAlgorithm);
        PrivateKey key = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        return key;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Exception Stack:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.parseMsg(RSACore.java:214)
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.priCrypt(RSACore.java:144)
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.rsa(RSACore.java:124)
>       at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:362)
>       at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
>       at Entities.RsaKeys.decrypt(RsaKeys.java:72)
>       at DecryptTest.getRsaPrivateKey(DecryptTest.java:36)
>       at DecryptTest.testOne(DecryptTest.java:26)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Changed code. Added ability to encrypt. Can now print the decrypted string (if encrypted with code). Also added another way to make private key.

Been playing around with it. I can successfully encrypt and decrypt a random string.

Comment: First sign and verify something (empty byte array for all we care) with the private and public key so you know they are correct. Then check that your ciphertext blocks are exactly 128 bytes (1024 / Byte.SIZE) in size after base 64 decoding them. Happy debugging, check out hybrid crypto when you have the time.

Comment: You should not initialize the cipher every time around the loop, surely?

Comment: @EJP Not required indeed - `doFinal` already resets the cipher to the init stage, but since RSA doesn't have anything resembling a key schedule or something like that it may not hurt *that* much.

Comment: Include the debugging output from your program. It would show lengths of the modulus and ciphertext, which would indicate which you've got wrong. Also, this is the wrong way to use RSA, and the example you followed is not exemplary. Encrypt data with a symmetric cipher like AES using a one-time key, then encrypt that key with RSA.

Comment: base64BlockSize: 172 | Iterations: 1 | Byte Array Encrypted String Length (Base64 Decoded): 128 **    Its failing when it tries to decrypt the encrypted string. Also. My code works on encrypting and decrypting a string (using the un-encrypted string).